# Problem while linux kernel complie: "No rule to make target 'moudles_install'"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

**I'm not pretty good at English, so there are maybe some spell and/or grammar issues.**

When I compile linux kernel version 4.8.0, i encountered with issues.

**Environment**: Ubuntu 20.04 running on Parallels Desktop, virtual machine running on macOS 10.15.5. Linux kernel source code stored on external pen drive, mounted on the virtual machine. followed those commands:

```
make (Anwser all questions use enter)
make modules_install
sudo make install
```

After that, I got this:
[Screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvWaF.jpg)

Comment: You need to fix your clock first.  make can fail when dates are in the future.

Comment: Also it looks like you are not using the required compiler version.  Did you read README?